# Tricky SQL for a report

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following four columns.

```
Student_Id  
Course_Id  
Seq_No  
Date_Taken
```

Looking for any help on SQL for oracle db to get the following report.
Also is it possible to get the report in a single query using sub queries?

```
Course_ID                           | CR150   
=============================================
Total students Taken                | 5  
Students Taken this as First Course | 3  
Only Course  Taken by Students      | 3  
Students Taken 2 Courses            | 2
```

Comment: You get a lot more value out of your homework if you do it yourself.

Comment: At least, get started by writing the individual queries that will get those four statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a nested query.  The inner query should use an analytic query to select by student and course, how many courses the student is taking, and which course this is in sequence.  Then you can use that in the FROM of a group by query that gives the report that you want.

I could give you the SQL but won't because it is your homework problem, not mine.  But http://www.orafaq.com/node/55 may help you learn how to do analytic queries.

Comment: Thank you btilly for the direction. I will read the link and learn those analytic queries. By the way, that is not my home work. Its my work related. I just made up a question to suit the task at my hand.